# Google Sheet Query: Why "!= ' '" doesn't work?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, syntax, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

To select cells that are not empty, we have to use something like

```
SELECT * WHERE A IS NOT NULL
```

If I replace it with

```
   SELECT * WHERE A != ''
```

or

```
   SELECT * WHERE A != ' '
```

There will be no error but nothing is returned.

Why is this?

Comment: `' '` is not the same as `''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when referring to a null cell try:

```
"where A <> ''"
```

[image]

or:

```
"where not A = ''"
```

[image]

or:

```
"where not A matches ''"
```

[image]

or:

```
"where not A matches '^$'"
```

[image]

or:

```
"where not A like ''"
```

[image]

but even yours:

```
"where A != ''"
```

[image]

and:

```
"where A is not null"
```

[image]

will work...

the real issue is the shabby query behavior when you got a mixed dataset (numeric + plain text) and query makes the wrong assumption that you don't need the minority of the set:

[image]

where in such case you will need to force the formatting like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(A:A&"", "where Col1 is not null", ))
```

[image]

notice the `Col1` syntax

but there are cases when you need not to convert numeric values into plain text values so in such case it is better to use:

```
=FILTER(A:A, A:A<>"")
```

[image]